# GWT Runtime Dependencies

Tags: java, gwt, jar, dependencies, runtime

**Please note**, not interested in using the Google-Eclipse plugin; I want to manage all dependencies manually.

Just downloaded the [GWT 2.5.1 SDK](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/download) and am looking at all the JARs it ships with:

```
gwt-api-checker.jar     requestfactory-apt-src.jar
gwt-codeserver.jar      requestfactory-client.jar
gwt-dev.jar             requestfactory-client-src.jar
gwt-elemental.jar       requestfactory-client+src.jar
gwt-servlet-deps.jar    requestfactory-server.jar
gwt-servlet.jar         requestfactory-server-src.jar
gwt-soyc-vis.jar        requestfactory-server+src.jar
gwt-user.jar            validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
requestfactory-apt.jar  validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
```

Obviously, some of these JARs are for the SDK (`gwt-dev.jar`, `gwt-codeserver.jar`, etc.) but some will be necessary to be included in my WAR's `WEB-INF/lib` directory so that they are available to the runtime classpath.

So I ask, **which of the above JARs are runtime dependencies?** Nothing in the release notes, GWT's website, or the SDK documentation...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any of these libraries in your `WEB-INF/lib`. You need only deploy the GWT compiled classes.

The only reason you would require GWT libraries in your deployed web app is if you used GWT functionality in your server-side code (e.g. GWT RPC).

---

Update to reflect comment:

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory#allTogether.

Comment: Ahhh, gotchya @cklab (+1) - I plan on using RequestFactory, so can I assume I need to include all the `requestfactory-*.jars`?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja `requestfactory-server.jar` and `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` should suffice.