# NoClassFoundError runtime at tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, vaadin, m2eclipse

```
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasClickHandlers at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at ...
```

However at the WEB-INF/lib there is the jar which contains the class...

But tomcat shows:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Boss\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\applicLiquidator\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-dev-2.3.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
márc. 10, 2014 1:54:55 DU org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\Boss\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\applicLiquidator\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-user-2.3.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

So how can i make these classes available in runtime when they violate servlet.class?

**Update**:
Seems like a vicious circle because of Servlet.class violation and because of the needs of this jars at runtime:(

**POM. XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Reignsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>Liquidator</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.2</version>
    <name>Felszámoló Ügyviteli Rendszer</name>
    <ciManagement>
        <system>hudson</system>
        <url>http://reign.ti:58084/jenkins/job/Liquidator%20-%20Maven/</url>
    </ciManagement>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>6.8.13</vaadin.version>
        <jpacontainer.version>2.0.0</jpacontainer.version>
        <gwt.version>2.3.0</gwt.version>
        <gwt.plugin.version>2.3.0-1</gwt.plugin.version>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <path>/applicLiquidator</path>
        <update>true</update>
        <username>tomcat</username>
        <password>tomcat</password>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0</artifactId>
            <version>${jpacontainer.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>customfield</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>beanvalidation-addon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>filteringtable</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>popupbutton</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.160</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymockclassextension</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>confirmdialog</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for PDF document generatioon -->
        <!-- 1.0 rather than 1.1 due to http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/Maven-dependencies-for-fop-1-1-td37437.html -->
        <dependency> 
          <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
          <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for Office document generation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version> 3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for generating HTML pages, a HTML template engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for drawing with GWT graphics  -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
           <artifactId>gwt-graphics</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            gwt-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [${gwt.plugin.version},)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${url}</url>
                        <username>${username}</username>
                        <password>${password}</password>
                        <path>${path}</path>
                        <update>${update}</update>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Uncomment to enable widgetset compilation -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwt.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                        </webappDirectory>
                        <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                        </hostedWebapp>
                        <noServer>true</noServer>
                        <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                        <style>OBF</style>
                        <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>resources</goal>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have a look at [GWT Runtime Dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797749/)

Comment: Please share your pom.xml.

Comment: Ok, i will post it and thanks every help!

Comment: gwt-dev is required only for dev mode. Try it after changing its scope to compile. I can't say that it will cause NoClassDefFoundError. Just try my answer also.

Comment: And can it cause NoClassDefFoundError? Ok, i try it, thanks!

Comment: So now it only says: INFO: validateJarFile(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\wtpwebapps\applicLiquidator\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-user-2.3.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class... But still offending and still do not load it, and still not found the class because of this : (

Comment: try it after adding `javax.servlet-api` dependency at the top in you pom.xml. That's why it is defined as provided means jboss server will provide it.

Comment: I can try it but i feels i should not do it because container should handle the servlet-api... Check it now...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49407/discussion-between-braj-and-czupe)

Comment: I'd bet the problem is a bad interaction between Maven and Eclipse WTP. Maven won't put gwt-user and gwt-dev into your `WEB-INF/lib` as they have `<scope>provided</scope>`, but here you're using WTP and who knows what that beast does…

Comment: The jars are the WEB-INF/lib and it says:
\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-user-2.3.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are bundling a version of Servlet in your application.

Tomcat doesn't like this so it stops loading and it simply doesn't get to the class you actually need. If you are using maven, set the servlet dependency to:

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

**UPDATE**

The relevant passage is:

```
The classloader that a container uses to load a servlet in a WAR must 
allow the developer to load any resources contained in library JARs within 
the WAR following normal J2SE semantics using getResource. 
It must not allow the WAR to override J2SE or Java servlet API classes.
It is further recommended that the loader not allow servlets in the WAR
access to the web container’s implementation classes.
It is recommended also that the application class loader be implemented
so that classes and resources packaged within the WAR are loaded in
preference to classes and resources residing in container-wide library JARs.
```

Please post your maven pom dependencies and double check that the resulting war file does not contain a jar that contains the servlet class.

Comment: Nice idea, but already have scope provided in maven : (
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
Any idea about  " jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class" ???! I think this is the cause why not loaded, but how can i force to load it?:(

Comment: You are not allowed to replace standard java classes like javax.servlet.Servlet. Don't include javax.servlet.Servlet in your WAR file!

Comment: I kindly as please help Klas, i know you are a big vaadin magician:) I saw your nick in vaadin forums!